# In Android studio 3.0, can't enable developer option

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm not finding "Developer option" or "About phone" in settings of Android-studio 3.0, and I need one of them to run my app on a real device.

Comment: Android studio is only about development. Do you mean the Developer options and "About phone" settings of an Android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those settings are on the phone itself, plug in the phone via USB with android studio running and it should ask you if you want to enable debugging on the phone.
About phone is located in the phone settings, usually down at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm french and in the official Android Studio doc, I haven't understand that they are speaking about the device. Now, it's working.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to enable the Developer mode on the phone before these options show up.

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm french and in the official Android Studio doc, I haven't understand that they are speaking about the device. Now, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Those settings can be found in your device's settings, not in the Android Studio Settings

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm french and in the official Android Studio doc, I haven't understand that they are speaking about the device. Now, it's working.